# Bar graphs must be dynamically generated based on the user input

Tags: java, loops

I can only use loops. I'm not able to use arrays.

my output looks like:

```
How many stores are there?: 5

Enter the total sales for Store 1: 1000
Enter the total sales for Store 2: 1200
Enter the total sales for Store 3: 1800
Enter the total sales for Store 4: 800
Enter the total sales for Store 5: 1900

GRAPH OF TOTAL SALES
(Each * = $100)
Store 1: **********
Store 2: ************
Store 3: ******************
Store 4: ********
Store 5: *******************
```

But I got :

```
GRAPH OF TOTAL SALES
(Each * = $100)
Store 1 : ********************
Store 2 : ********************
Store 3 : ********************
Store 4 : ********************
Store 5 : ********************
```

here is my code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("How many stores are there?: ");
int stores = input.nextInt();
int s = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < stores; i++){
    System.out.println("Enter the total sales for Store " + (i + 1) + " : " );
    s = input.nextInt();
}

System.out.println("GRAPH OF TOTAL SALES");
System.out.println("(Each * = $100)");

for(int i1 = 0; i1 < stores; i1++) {
   System.out.print( "Store " + (i1 + 1) + " : ");

   for(int t = 0; t <= s/100; t++) {
      System.out.print("*");
   }
   System.out.println( );
}
```

Where am I wrong in my code?

Thanks !

Comment: `s` in the inner loop is always the same value

Comment: What is stores? Can you give the entire code?

Comment: s is my user input values

Comment: There is my full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just need to change the condition

```
t < s/100
```

in the inner for with

```
t < stores[i1]
```

if stores is an array of integers. Also, you forget to put **stores.length** instead of **stores**, but I would have to see the whole code first. Hope this could help you!

EDIT:

The problem in your code is that you keep overriding the value of s every time you ask for a user input. The solution, if you can't use arrays or data structures, is to ask for the input in the for loop and print the result in the end of every iteration.

Your code will look like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("How many stores are there?: ");
int stores = input.nextInt();
int s = 0;
System.out.println("GRAPH OF TOTAL SALES"); System.out.println("(Each * = $100)");

for(int i1 = 0; i1 < stores; i1++) {
   System.out.println("Enter the total sales for Store " + (i1 + 1) + " : ");
   System.out.print( "Store " + (i1 + 1) + " : ");
   s = input.nextInt();
   for(int t = 0; t < s/100; t++) {
      System.out.print("*");
   }
   System.out.println( );
}
input.close();
```

Comment: I can't use array. I have to use loops

Comment: what if i want output in this format?  How many stores are there?: 5

Enter the total sales for Store 1: 1000
Enter the total sales for Store 2: 1200
Enter the total sales for Store 3: 1800
Enter the total sales for Store 4: 800
Enter the total sales for Store 5: 1900
    
GRAPH OF TOTAL SALES
(Each * = $100)
Store 1: **********
Store 2: ************
Store 3: ******************
Store 4: ********
Store 5: *******************

Comment: Then you do need a data structure of some sort or an array :)

Answer (score 0):

Store every value you get from the user into an arraylist or some collection that can dynamically expand. When you're done reading the input from the user you iterate over your collection of inputs and each value becomes your s value when you print out the graphs. This means taking your code to print the graphs inside the iteration loop of your collection of inputs. Currently you have single variable to keep track of an unknown number of inputs so your last value entered will always be used for s. Do something like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("How many stores are there?: ");
int stores = input.nextInt();
ArrayList<Integer> s = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < stores; i++){
    System.out.println("Enter the total sales for Store " + (i + 1) + " : " );
    s.add(input.nextInt());
}
System.out.println("GRAPH OF TOTAL SALES"); System.out.println("(Each * = $100)");

   for(int i1 = 0; i1 < s.size(); i1++) {
           System.out.print( "Store " + (i1 + 1) + " : ");

       for(int t = 0; t <= s.get(i1)/100; t++) {
          System.out.print("*");
   }
   System.out.println( );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use arrays, then just append the resulting bar representation to a single string variable every time you receive a user input. In the end, you only need to display that single string when you are done with accepting user input.